# HtmlUnit - get href content from linkelement

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

i want to get the content of href attribute of an a-Tag from an URL.

Currently i do this and got this:

```
System.out.println("Output: " + scrapePage.getByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]").toString());

Output: [HtmlAnchor[<a href="this_url?page=125&amp;timezone=2" class="cell cell--list-item">]]
```

No i would extract only the part within the href attribute. Could anyone help, please?

Thx T.

Answer (score 0):

Have if found on my own :-) and using this

```
for (HtmlAnchor a : scrapePage.getAnchors()) {
    if (a.getHrefAttribute().contains("page")) {
        String url = a.getHrefAttribute();
        if (!url.startsWith("https")) {
            url = "https://www.mypage.net" + url;
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }
}
```